# Javascript call not working in JSF 2.2

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have this p:autocomplete calling script in `replaceCode()`.
`replaceCode()` does not call... I've put the script within `ui:define` as per convention; even tried putting within the same `h:form`...

Why doesn't this work and how to debug?

```
<ui:define>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function replaceCode()
        {
            alert("replaceCode() activates.");
            var role = document.deleteUserForm.role.value;
            if (role == 'L') {
                var str = "Lead";
            }
            else if (role == 'S') {
                var str = "Specialist";
            }       
            else if (role == 'B') {
                var str = "Developer"
            }
            document.deleteUserForm.role.value = str;

            var adminAccess = document.deleteUserForm.adminAccess.value;
            if (role == '0') {
                var str = "Yes";
            }
            else if (role == '999') {
                var str = "No";
            }               
            document.deleteUserForm.adminAccess.value = str;            
        }
</script>
.
.
<h:form>
.
.
<p:autoComplete id="associateID" appendTo="@this"   
    value="#{adminPageBean.superUser.superUserEmpId}"
    completeMethod="#{adminPageBean.completeAssociateID}"
    multiple="false" minQueryLength="2" queryDelay="1000"
    required="true" requiredMessage="Please select Associate ID." 
    dropdown="true" scrollHeight="250" placeholder="(Enter min. 2 chars.)"
    oncomplete="replaceCode();">
    <f:validateLength minimum="6"/> 
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
    listener="#{adminPageBean.handleAssociateIDSelect}" update=":deleteUserForm" /> 
</p:autoComplete>   
.
.
</h:form>    
.
.
</ui:define>
```

Comment: Where do you call replaceCode function?

Comment: p:autoComplete -> oncomplete="replaceCode();"

Comment: So it worked with jsf 2.1?

Comment: An [mcve] is the way to start

Comment: I got it to work! Changes: 1.  var role = document.getElementById("deleteUserForm:roleDeleteUser").value;  var adminAccess = document.getElementById("deleteUserForm:adminAccessDeleteUser").value; 2. Removed oncomplete="replaceCode()" from p:autoComplete to p:ajax